# Using a bound parameter in Select portion of statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pass a variable in the select portion of one of my mysql statements here but am not getting the desired result. Heres a snippet of my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
    $send='ra_dccr.'.$_GET['send'];
}

$query = $link->prepare("SELECT locale.id, locale.provider_num, locale.provider_name, :var as ccr
                        FROM `ra_dccr`
                        INNER JOIN `locale`
                        ON ra_dccr.id = locale.id
                        WHERE locale.report_record_num LIKE concat ('%',:recordnum,'%')

$query->bindParam(':var', $send, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

My issue is that `ccr` is displaying as `ra_dccr.{value of $send}`
instead of the actual value that should be pulled from the database when I fetch the result. Am I actually allowed to use variables in this way in a select statement? How can I get sql to look for the appropriate column name this way. For instance if send is ct_scan, it should look for ra_dccr.ct_scan and then pull the val.

Thanks in advance

Heres an image of what is happening

[image: Output]

Comment: There are issues with your code. The parameter `recordnum` is not bound at all, and the query string is never closed. This code won't even run. Also, please specify what the data looks like, and what are the desired result and the result you currently have. That way we may quickly spot the error.

Comment: It's a snippet....Read what I wrote at the top. I'll add a picture of the output. Don't worry whether my code runs or not, the query is much longer than what I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Parameters are for passing *values* to a query. And that's what happens here: the value you pass to `:var` is returned literally.

If you want to use a dynamic field name, build the query using the actual field name without using bind parameters:

```
"SELECT locale.id, locale.provider_num, locale.provider_name, $send as ccr
```

The best way to do this is to verify the value of $_GET['send'] first. Maybe you can even check it against a whitelist of allowed fields.

```
if (!in_array($_GET['send'], array('field1', 'field3', 'field30'))) {
  die('invalid field!');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to prevent injection and am I not doing the exact same thing with the bindParam method?

Comment: It works, I am just worried about having a variable directly in my statement

Comment: Yeah, make sure to sanitize it. That is, make sure it contains only characters valid to a field name, or better, validate it against a whitelist of allowed fields. See edit.